# I upload a picture successfully to the firebase storage but the download url is not stored in the database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to save the stored image's url in the database however it doesn't successfully do that. It doesn't show any url's in the database as it seemingly skips the instructions in the following saveButton function.

```
@IBAction func saveButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profileImages").child(id!)

    if let uploadData = profilePicture.image?.pngData(){

        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }

            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let downUrl = url {

                    Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(self.id!).child("profileImageUrl").setValue(downUrl)
                }
            })
        }



    }else{
        Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(self.id!).child("profileImageUrl").setValue("default")

    }

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMainPage", sender: self)

}
```

}

Comment: You must get a warning in the terminal? Make sure the downUrl  is a string. So check if downUrl.stringValue works. And if that doesn't work, set up a completion handle for the setValue to catch the error message.

Comment: "it seemingly skips the instructions" It sounds like you're stepping through the code in the debugger. Some of the methods you call are asynchronous, which means you won't be able to step into them. Instead set breakpoints (for example on `if error != nil{` and `if let downUrl = url {`) and then run it again in the debugger to see if the breakpoints get hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace

```
storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let downUrl = url {

                    Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(self.id!).child("profileImageUrl").setValue(downUrl)
                }
            })
```

by

```
let pat = (metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString.description)
let link = pat! //Link of image
Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(self.id!).child("profileImageUrl").setValue(link)
```